# AdMob - Same banner ID for different build types?

Tags: android, firebase, admob

I am currently developing an Android app and I planning to have some ads in it.
I wanted to use AdMob for the ads.

The problem is that I have different build configurations for debug and release builds (with different package IDs) which are also linked to Firebase as two different apps.
Is it possible to use the same AdMob banner ID in debug and release builds or do I need different IDs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create two different apps in Admob . Create separate banners for this apps. And use them .